# Has the internal SATA mobile rack fried the HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

I just built a machine with a Coolermaster Silencio case that has an internal SATA mobile rack. After booting to Windows 7, I inserted a 2TB SATA HDD and the machine crashed. Now that 2TB HDD is no longer recognised; not in my SATA to USB 3.0 caddie, nor when connected directly to the motherboard of another machine. Any thoughts on what happened? Is the HDD permanently fried?

Comment: "I believe that the problem is that the power connector was connected to the X-Dock backwards" (#8: http://forums.hexus.net/chassis-mods/271301-coolermaster-silencio-550-x-dock-3-5-sata-warning.html ) Poster #8 claims the plug is reversible. Check the pinouts on the dock power plug?

Comment: Thanks Yorik, I'll check the pin outs. Looks like the drive is fried, though.

Answer (score 0):

"I believe that the problem is that the power connector was connected to the X-Dock backwards" (#8: forums.hexus.net/chassis-mods/… ) Poster #8 claims the plug is reversible. Check the pinouts on the dock power plug?